How to handle modal dialog using C# and VUEJS in selenium webdriver?
DuplicateCancel
In the html below, How to handle the button "Duplicate" in a modal box using C# and Web Driver based on VUEJS?

HTML: DuplicateCancel

What do you mean by "handle"? Are you having difficulty obtaining a reference to the button, or firing its click event? Please be more specific about the exact problem you want help with.
